# SQL speed: Return each date in date range and count() for each

Tags: sql, sql-server

My goal is to return each date in a date range and count() all records for each date.

```
MyTable
-------------------------------
| OrderId |   DateFinalized   |
-------------------------------
|   51    | 2016-1-3 12:50:34 |
|   55    | 2016-1-4 10:01:56 |
|   73    | 2016-1-4 11:52:02 |
|   93    | 2016-1-6 01:35:16 |
|   104   | 2016-1-6 02:40:47 |
-------------------------------
```

The challenge is to include the dates with no orders as well. Using `MyTable` above, if the date range is between `2016-1-1` and `2016-1-6`, the desired output would be:

```
---------------------
|  MyDate  | Orders |
---------------------
| 2016-1-1 |   0    |
| 2016-1-2 |   0    |
| 2016-1-3 |   1    |
| 2016-1-4 |   2    |
| 2016-1-5 |   0    |
| 2016-1-6 |   2    |
---------------------
```

To accomplish this I used this query to select the **dates only** and it is exectued **under 1 second**:

```
declare @startdate datetime = '1/1/2016';
declare @enddate datetime = '1/1/2017';

with [dates] as (
    select convert(date, @startdate) as [date] 
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, [date])
    from [dates]
    where [date] < @enddate 
)
select 
[date]
from [dates] 
where [date] between @startdate and @enddate
order by [date] desc
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

When I select **order count grouped by date** as you see it below, it only takes **1 second** as well:

```
declare @startdate datetime = '2/1/2016';
declare @enddate datetime = '1/1/2017';
select 
convert(date,DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, datefinalized), 0))  as Dates,
count(OrderID) as OrderCount
from orders 
where datefinalized between @startdate and @enddate
GROUP BY DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, datefinalized), 0)
order by DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, datefinalized), 0) desc
```

The problem is that when I combine these two queries in a single SQL statement. **`LEFT JOIN`** takes **20 seconds**(!!!) to execute. I tried a sub-query for giggles and it wasn't much better at **13 seconds**:

**How can I efficiently join the resulting data sets?**

Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Use indexes: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html

Comment: Try using a numbers table instead of a recursive cte. 
I've used [rextester to check it but couldn't reproduce the problem.](http://rextester.com/MFEOV63797)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a recursive cte is one of the worst ways to generate a range of dates. Using a stacked cte is [much faster](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3) for generating the date range on demand than using a recursive cte.

If you are going to be using it across many rows, or long durations, or you will be running this sort of operation more than once, you would be better off just creating a `Dates` or `Calendar` table.

For only 152kb in memory, you can have 30 years of dates in a table, and you could use it like so:

```
/* dates table */ 
declare @fromdate date = '20000101';
declare @years    int  = 30;
/* 30 years, 19 used data pages ~152kb in memory, ~264kb on disk */
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
select top (datediff(day, @fromdate,dateadd(year,@years,@fromdate)))
    [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
into dbo.Dates
from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo 
               cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK
order by [Date];

create unique clustered index ix_dbo_Dates_date 
  on dbo.Dates([Date]);
```

and query it like so:

```
select
    d.[Date]
  , OrderCount = count(o.OrderID)
from dates d
  left join orders o
    on convert(date,o.OrderDate) = d.[Date]
group by d.[Date]
order by d.[Date] desc
```

Number and Calendar table reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 3 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)
- [Creating a Date Table/Dimension in SQL Server 2008 - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/06/creating-a-date-tabledimension-for-sql-server-2008/)
- [Calendar Tables - Why You Need One - David Stein](http://www.made2mentor.com/2011/04/calendar-tables-why-you-need-one/)
- [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server - Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)
- [TSQL Function to Determine Holidays in SQL Server - Tim Cullen](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1537/tsql-function-to-determine-holidays-in-sql-server/)
- [F_TABLE_DATE - Michael Valentine Jones](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61519)

---

If you really do not want a calendar table, you can just use the stacked cte portion:

```
declare @fromdate date = '20160101';
declare @years    int  = 1;
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, dates as (
  select top (datediff(day, @fromdate,dateadd(year,@years,@fromdate)))
      [Date]=convert(date,dateadd(day,row_number() over(order by (select 1))-1,@fromdate))
  from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo 
                /* cross join n as tenK cross join n as hundredK */
   order by [Date]
)
select
    d.[Date]
  , OrderCount = count(o.OrderID)
from dates d
  left join orders o
    on convert(date,o.OrderDate) = d.[Date]
group by d.[Date]
order by d.[Date] desc
```